# Solr: How to update a document with unique ID

Tags: solr

Could you please help. I have to update a Solr document by its unique identifier. Say, I have a document like:

```
    {
      "text": "qwe",
      "id": "01a3aa6db06d39e8",
      "_version_": 1471599607983112200
    }
```

I want to update the field "phrase", so I POST the following to 127.0.0.1:8983/solr/update/?commit=true:

```
    [
      {
        "id" : "01a3aa6db06d39e8",
        "text" : {"set":"qwe. updated"}
      }
    ]
```

Solr says 400 Bad Request and returns the following:

```
    {
      "responseHeader":
        {
          "status":400,"QTime":0},
          "error":{"msg":"Document contains multiple values for uniqueKey field: id=[01a3aa6db06d39e8, 0000000000000000]","code":400}
        }
    }
```

How the document containing a unique key can be properly updated?

Comment: Can you please post your `<field name="id" … />` from your schema.xml?

Comment: <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />  
...  
<field name="text" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>  
...
  <dynamicField name="*_en"  type="text_en"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

Comment: You should have a field with `name="id"`. Can you post that one please?

Comment: <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

Comment: Could it be that you have more than one field with `name="id"`? If not, could you please post your schema.xml and solrconfig.xml to some pastebin?

Comment: Did you start with an empty index before adding the document, or did you change the uniqueKey value AFTER indexing one or more documents as a test?

Comment: lxd, thanks for help! Seems the same problem was discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058795/it-is-possible-to-update-uniquekey-in-solr-4. The only way to update the documents having unique keys is the "indirect" update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
{"id":"01a3aa6db06d39e8","text":"hello world , this is an update"}
```

If you want to make text as a multidimensional array like mongodb, that cannot be accommodate in solr but there are ways to it, a bit messy.

If you are using a script to update a doc and I think you are using a loop include the commit and the instantiate inside the while loop like this one on PHP:

```
while($row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $client = new SolrClient($options);

    $doc = new SolrInputDocument();
    $doc->addField('id', $row['id']);       
    $doc->addField('date', '2015-06-01T00:00:0.0Z');
    $doc->addField('name', $row['name']);       
    $updateResponse = $client->addDocument($doc);
}   
$client->commit();
```